# Using several csv files of different sizes to build a CNN model in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I would like to create a CNN model in Python and I have organized my data in such a way that I have 100 csv files with different sizes (all of them have 141 colunms but some have 33 rows and others have 70 rows). All of those files can be categorized in 6 different categories. All the examples that I have seen so far for buiding a CNN model are using either just one dataset in pandas or using several images of the same size. So the question would be, Can I use my data for creating a CNN model in this fashion? If yes, Can anyone give me some tricks or/and tips of how to?
Thanks a lot in advance!

I have seen some Tensorflow or PyTorch examples but I dont know how to use them with my data

Comment: Are your data images or tabular numeric data? Do all of those 141 columns have the same meaning?

Comment: all of it is numeric data

Comment: Is there a reason that the files are separated? Like, is there some information on presented as "what file this data is in" that needs to be used? You mentioned only 6 classes but 100 files, so I am assuming it is not one file per class.

Comment: Umm, each file represents, lets say "one try", and I will have 100 tries. Moreover, each of those tries can "score" a category from A to F. Now, in each file, 138 of the columns represent parameters configuration for that specific row. Do you think I should simply combine all the files? If so, I am in doubt of how then use the full data without losing any information.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of a "try". How is a try related to each row? What distinguishes one try from the next

Comment: what I referred as "try" is an independent process. For example, lets say we are 100 people trying to get from point A to point B. Each of those files grab the data of each persons "try". So all of the 100 are independent. Does that make sense for an answer?

Comment: And the rows are the "different ways a person gets from A to B"? Then if you want to predict something "for each different person", there is no other way than to make a model for each person. If you want to make a model for the general "person" but your data just happens to be different configurations by different persons, then you can concatenate everything, no information is lost there.

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking of. Thanks :)

Comment: I will add this as an answer later

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the reason that the data are separated in different files in the first place and what you want to achieve.

If each file contains observations for a different entity AND you want to predict observations about EACH specific known entity, you can build a model for each entity. In this case, the entities with more training data will of course have better results.

Still, if the difference between those entities can be described with numerical values, depending on the exact problem, you can also try adding those to the training data and then concatenating everything. In this case, the added features will make the final classification to better classify the observations of each different entity without building 100 models. Note however that this could work only if the "qualities" of the entities actually affect the observations in some degree, otherwise (if the observations are randomly distributed amongst the entities) the results will probably be worse.

If however the observations of different entities are needed to train a model that works for any entity (including unknown ones), the data can be concatenated to a single table (pandas DataFrames were mentioned in the question) and then train your model with this combined dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply and suggestion. I will concatenate the files and give it a go. As you said, what I would like to do is to make some predictions for the 101th, etc..